Treadmill Problem: Considering the design of the plane
My coworker and I were discussing the treadmill problem from this old post1. I understand that the plane could theoretically fly given that the thrust is generated by the airflow.
Is this true for all types of planes?
My coworker thinks the jet engine with an engine underneath the wings will not fly. He argues that the engine will only create an airflow underneath the wings, not above the wings. I am inclined to agree, but I am not convinced. I can see the airflow generated by the turbines affecting the airflow around the entire plane as well.
I was looking for an airflow diagram of a stationary jet with the engines on. I have not been able to one.
I would appreciate an answer and a reason to why, or why not, the design matters.

"My coworker thinks the jet engine with an engine underneath the wings will not fly. " Have you or your coworker ever looked at an airliner?

The engines do not generate the flow around the airplane.  They grab air in front and throw it to the back.  By doing so, they generate thrust.  Thrust causes acceleration, enough acceleration and you achieve some velocity through the air.  Once at some velocity through the air, the overall shape of the aircraft causes the flowfield that causes lift.

@RobMcDonald Since in this hypothetical question, the plane will be stationary relative to the ground, it will not have velocity through the air? Or the fact that is has thrust, it can have velocity through the air, even if its stationary relative to the ground?

@WPNSGuy Yes. To be more specific, the turbines are in front of the wings at a lower height than the wings. Does this change the fact whether the plane can fly or not on a treadmill?

@trying2understand - the engines, no matter where they are, have a singular purpose. To push stuff out the back, in order to move the whole aircraft forward. This "moving forward" creates airflow over the wings. Which is what allows the aircraft to leave the ground and fly. A "treadmill" has nothing to do with it.

@trying2understand The aircraft will start with zero velocity relative to the ground -- and the wheels are spinning because of the treadmill.  The thrust of the engines will accelerate the aircraft relative to the ground (and the air).  The wheels will have to spin even faster.  When the aircraft reaches an airspeed fast enough to fly, it will be able to do so.  The treadmill just causes higher wheel speed.  Airplane wheels are like a shopping cart -- they just spin, they do not drive anything.

if the treadmill is moving in take off direction and fast enough compared to the air, the plane could brake and be able to take off (for a short time) - basically similar to a glider being pulled by a motorplane or winch. But after starting to fly and losing contact with the treadmill, velocity would decrease (air friction) and consequently it would lose lift and land. If running backwards, the treadmill would increase friction (wheels) and increase the time for the plane to reach rotation velocity (or even hinder it from being reached) -- always ignoring air being moved by the treadmill

@DeltaLima: if you reopen this question (or even better, if you reopen the question in the link) I'd be glad to give an answer to this treadmill problem

The simple and correct solution to the treadmill problem holds true for all aircraft, except those propelled by wheels. No known aircraft is propelled by wheels; unlike a car, an aircraft's wheels are free-spinning, and are often replaced by skis or floats when those suit the terrain better.
The "treadmill problem" isn't a serious physics paradox. It was invented because a lot more people drive cars than know any law of math or physics.
Still, to try and put another nail in its coffin, consider a world without cars. Apply the treadmill problem to a horse-pulled cart, where the horse is outside the treadmill. Will the treadmill inconvenience the horse? Yes, it will create some extra friction. Will it stop the horse from pulling the cart? No. The horse can, if nothing else, drag the wheels across the treadmill.
Now, if we try to bring this into the real world, it's more complicated. No real treadmill can run infinitely fast. If the treadmill is infinitely fast, it can overheat or blow the tires, damaging the aircraft. If both treadmill is infinitely fast, but the wheels perfectly durable, the treadmill will create an air cushion, which is a much better anti-friction device than wheels.
If both the treadmill and the aircraft are subject to real-world engineering limitations, such a contraption won't stop airliners or jet fighters, but it could affect a homebuilt ultralight that can't take a bit more drag.

For another coffin nail, consider an aircraft without wheels. Skis on snow, or floats on water. Magically, they still leave the surface and fly.

If you’re talking about the hypothetical 747 on a treadmill problem, go back and consider the fundamental forces acting on the aircraft during this exercise.
For simplicity some assumptions have to be made:

Treadmill is of sufficient length to allow the aircraft to accelerate to Vr, achieve liftoff and accelerate to V2 while at least 35 ft above the departure end of treadmill belt.

While the tyres make perfect contact with the treadmill belt and rotate to match the belt speed, there is no frictional impedance on the forward motion of the aircraft.

The lift vector generated by the wings is assumed to be perpendicular to the treadmill surface.

The thrust vector from the engine acts parallel to the surface of the treadmill belt but acts in the opposite direction of belt movement.


When the pilot advances the engines to full thrust, the thrust force is the only force acting in the horizontal direction.  This will cause the airframe to accelerate forward at a rate proportional to Newton’s First Law REGARDLESS of how fast the treadmill and the wheels turn.
Initially there is some airflow under the wings of the jet due to the fan exhaust and hot exhaust gases from the engine gas generators.  As the jet picks up speed, ram air begins to flow around the wing, just as in a normal takeoff.  With enough forward speed, movement of this ram air around the wings, combined with an increase in angle of attack on the wings due to raising the nose off the treadmill belt, generates enough lift to overcome the force of gravity and lift the airplane off the belt and into the sky.
The mass flow rate of the jet wash alone, nor its interaction with the lower surface of the wing, is not sufficient to generate enough lift to fly.  The airplane MUST be physically moving forward with respect to an independent viewer stationary on the ground and not standing on the treadmill.  The change in momentum of the ram airflow moving around the wings is what causes the airplane to fly.
